# Java Implementation of Flash API

Tags: java, flash, actionscript-3, api, actionscript

Just curious to see people's opinions:

Has anyone thought about implementing the Flash player API in Java? Controlling sprites, graphics, media, etc is so easy to do in Flash, it seems like it would only make sense to have a similar API in Java.

Comment: Do you mean create a Flash Player that runs existing SWF's through Java or rewrite the Flash Actionscript Library (e.g. Sprite, EventDispatcher, TextField) in Java?

Comment: I mean the latter. The former has already been accomplished -- http://www.jpackages.com/jflashplayer/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[JFlash](https://jflash.dev.java.net/) started an effort to do this.  I do not know of any active project doing this, though.

Answer (score 1):

See [JavaFX](http://www.sun.com/software/javafx/)

Comment: Thanks for this reference -- though I'm wondering how useful a literal implementation of the Flash player API would be to ActionScript developers wishing to migrate.

Comment: I'm not sure there's a huge need - from what I've listened to on podcasts, the Adobe stack (well, Flex anyhow) integrates really well with Java (the developer tools provide easy ways of connecting to java code/software); given that, why would you want to get an emulator? And again, Java has JavaFX. Just switch or don't :)